# Four router and one gateway address, can it be done ? (Cisco)

Tags: cisco, router

I have 4 routers in my LAN. All of them have different IP addresses. But I want to have one gateway address for my LAN. How can I do that ? Thanks in advance.

Notes:

-I do not want to use HSRP or any other redundancy option.

-Is it possible to give same secondary ip address to all four routers so that I have one gateway address.

-I have this kind of setup for redundancy. However, I have to use 4 routers. Because, my Routers do not support PIM redundancy. And actually I do not want to use a passive way of redundancy.

- I have lots of static IP addresses from my ISP.
- I am using NAT. But each Router has different Nat translations.

Comment: Please provide the business problem you are trying to solve. This may give us a better understanding of what needs to be done.

Comment: It sounds like you should redesign your network using more traditional, proven methods.

Comment: There are four types of device on the network. Each router will be configured by a computer. With this configurations that we are continuously making, we want to control internet connection of each device using NAT ( We are redirecting inbound and outbound packets using NAT.). And we want to use only one gateway address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know and from experience what you want is not viable. It will mess up your LAN.

I know it's possible to share the same IP on different interfaces on the same router with the ip unnumbered command.

Using the same IP on 4 different routers who connect to the same LAN, will create routing problems and data flow inconsistencies.

The protocols you are unwilling to use (HSRP, VRRP, GLBP), were created to address the specific problem you are facing.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably just add default routes on all the three routers that are not the default gateway so all the traffic is directed to them.

So: 
R1 has 192.168.1.254/24
R2 has 192.168.2.254/24
R3 has 192.168.3.254/24
R4 has 192.168.4.254/24

Say you want the gateway to be R1 then you will have R2, R3 and R4 to have a default route to 192.168.1.254

Comment: Never suggest static routes as a solution to a problem that routing protocols should be used to solve.

Comment: This solution will give me one gateway. But, devices on the LAN, need to be configured to use different gateway.( I have to enter IP of that three routers to devices on the LAN as a gateway). Also, if R1 fails, network will fail.